# How can i get return table dynamic result from a function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Can we use a function in order to get results from different tables and columns with respect to input in postgresql?

Sample: if a=1, the function will return talbe1 and 3 columns.
if a<>1, the function will return table2 and 4 columns and different data types.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1(
        a int
        )
        RETURNS TABLE(????) 
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
        COST 100
        VOLATILE 
        ROWS 1000   
    AS $BODY$
    begin  
        if (a=1) then 
                return query select a1,b1,c1 from  table1;  
         else 
              return query select a2,b2,c2,d2 from    table2;
        end  if;      
    END;
    $BODY$;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like that

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1(
        a int
        )
        RETURNS SET OF record
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
        COST 100
        VOLATILE 
        ROWS 1000   
    AS $BODY$
    begin  
        if (a=1) then 
                return query select a1,b1,c1 from  table1;  
         else 
              return query select a2,b2,c2,d2 from    table2;
        end  if;  
    return;
    END;
    $BODY$;
```

[Postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)

Comment: This will not work. it will throw error `a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"`

Comment: Yes you're right unless you run your query as `select * from public.func1(1) as (a1 varchar,b1 varchar,c1 varchar)`